# SentinelOne LinuxExtension - Azure

Tags: linux, azure, terraform, azure-rm

I am currently looking to deploy the SentinelOne agent via Terraform. There does not appear to be much documentation online for VM extension usage in terms of Terraform. Has anyone successfully deployed the S1 agent via Terraform extension? I am unclear on what to add to the settings/protected_settings blocks. Any help is appreciated.

```
  "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "example" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher            = "SentinelOne.LinuxExtension"
  type                 = "LinuxExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the settings/protected settings blocks in terraform

```py
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "example" {
  name                 = "hostname"
  virtual_machine_id   = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  publisher            = "SentinelOne.LinuxExtension"
  type                 = "LinuxExtension"
  type_handler_version = "1.0"
 
settings = <<SETTINGS
    {
        "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe -Command \"${local.powershell_command}\""
    }
SETTINGS
  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_machine.example
  ]
}
```

- `Settings` - The extension's settings are provided as a string-encoded JSON object.
- `protected settings` In the same way that settings are supplied as a JSON object in a string, the protected settings passed to the extension are also.

The keys in the `settings` and `protected settings` blocks must be case sensitive according to some VM Extensions. Make sure they are consistent with how Azure expects them (for example, the keys for the *JsonADDomainExtension* extension the keys are supposed to be in *TitleCase)*

***Reference:***  [azurerm_virtual_machine_extension](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine_extension)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I should have been specific. I am looking to know if anyone has successfully gotten this to work. If so, I am curious to know about the values added to the settings/protected_settings fields.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the plugin manually and checking the JSON output gives the following settings block:

```
{
    "LinuxAgentVersion": "22.4.1.2",
    "SiteToken": "<your_site_token_here"
}
```

Unfortunately, this leaves the one critical field required for installation out, since it's a protected setting.  That is the field name for the "Sentinel One Console API token".

**UPDATE:**
Working extension example after finding the correct JSON key value:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "testserver-sentinelone-extension" {
  name                      = "SentinelOneLinuxExtension"
  virtual_machine_id        = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.testserver.id
  publisher                 = "SentinelOne.LinuxExtension"
  type                      = "LinuxExtension"
  type_handler_version      = "1.2"
  automatic_upgrade_enabled = false
  settings                  = <<SETTINGS
    {
      "LinuxAgentVersion": "22.4.1.2",
      "SiteToken": "<your_site_token_here>"
    }
SETTINGS

  protected_settings = <<PROTECTEDSETTINGS
    {
      "SentinelOneConsoleAPIKey": "${var.sentinel_one_api_token}"
    }
PROTECTEDSETTINGS
}
```

**EDIT:** Figured it out by once again manually installing the extension on another test system, and then digging into the waagent logs on that VM to see what value was being queried by the enable.sh script.

```
# cat /var/lib/waagent/SentinelOne.LinuxExtension.LinuxExtension-1.2.0/scripts/enable.sh | grep Console
api_token=$(echo "$protected_settings_decrypted" | jq -r ".SentinelOneConsoleAPIKey")
```